# VHDL FSM Moving Average

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to write a VHDL moving average (evenly weighted) module that uses FSMD(ata). From what I understand, the states needed would be something like fetch, divide, output. Below is the process I wrote, but I feel like my logic is a bit off. Note that the data I'm averaging is just a constant array of 8 bit numbers, so I figured it should be fine to use a non-causal design.

The data has 64 entries, and at the moment the window for the average is 4.

```
process (clk,rst) is

    variable temp : integer range 0 to 1020;
    begin
        if rst = '1' then
            count  <= 0;
            n_state <= s0;
        elsif (clk'event and clk = '1') then
            c_state <= n_state;
            case c_state is
                when s0 =>
                    for i in 0 to (len) loop
                        temp := temp + pattern(count+i);
                    end loop;
                    n_state <= s1;
                when s1 =>
                    temp := temp/4;
                    n_state <= s2;
                when s2 =>
                    data <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(pattern(count),8));
                    data_avg <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(temp,8));
                    n_state <= s0;
                    count <= count+1;
                end case;
        end if;
    end process;
```

How wrong does this look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few problems I can see right away:

1. You don't [re-]initialize `temp` anywhere.
2. You don't have any limit checks for `count` (is it a subtype or just a `natural`/`integer`? What happens with `pattern(count+i)` when you approach the limit? How do you roll over?)
3. Your for-loop is `0 to len` - are you sure you didn't mean `0 to (len - 1)`?
4. Since your entire state decode process is clocked, you don't really need `n_state` at all. Note that you're not even initializing `c_state` (but you're still decoding it). Either make your state decode a separate combinational process or just get rid of `n_state` and assign to `c_state` directly.

Otherwise, it depends on your design goals. If you don't care about throughput but need to run at a very high clock rate, you might want to perform your addition sequentially instead of in parallel, for example.

Comment: thanks, that definitely does make things better. about the count rollover, I'm not sure really how to do it because for each pattern(count) up to 63, I want to display its value and the average of the window around it. so if i rollover at coun-len, it shouldn't go out of bounds but it will not show full data.

if i was doing a causal implementation i would have some delay at the start, is it a similar thing I need here but at the end?

Comment: my solution was:
elsif (clk event) then
    if count = 64 then
        count <= 0;
    else
        calculate
   end if

.And in the for loop i put an exit if count + i was greater than 63.

Answer (score 1):

Is it an exercise about using a FSM, or you just need to generate a vector containing the averages ?
If the input data are constants, all the calculations can be done during synthesis or at the beginning of simulation.

You can therefore write it as a simple function, as you would do in a 'normal' software programming language.

Here is an example :

```
TYPE array_byte IS ARRAY(natural RANGE <>) OF unsigned(7 DOWNTO 0);

CONSTANT pattern : array_byte(0 TO 63):=(0 => x"00",1 => x"10",2 => x"20",
                                       OTHERS => x"30");

FUNCTION average4(CONSTANT v : array_byte) RETURN array_byte IS
    VARIABLE vo : array_byte(0 TO v'length-5);
    VARIABLE temp : unsigned(9 DOWNTO 0);
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 0 TO v'length-5 LOOP
       temp:=(OTHERS =>'0');
       FOR j IN 0 TO 3 LOOP
          temp:=temp + v(i+j);
       END LOOP;
       temp:=temp / 4;
       vo(i):=temp(7 DOWNTO 0);
    END LOOP;
    RETURN vo;
 END FUNCTION;

 CONSTANT vout : array_byte(0 TO 59):=average4(pattern);
```